# C++ Accessing a class from a function it is not defined in

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm new to C++ and having a bit of trouble with accessing variables inside a class. From what I've read on here so far creating globals is a really bad practice and not to do that, but I dont know how else to move access to a class around.

So far my searches have pointed me to set and get functions in the class, but I think I can only use them in the block where the object is defined.

Basically what I want to know is if I define a class object in main() then call a function in main like gameLoop() how do I access that object inside that new function without making the class object global.

For instance:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

class Word
{
    private:
        string m_word;
        int m_length;
    public:
        void set(string word, int length)
        {
            m_word = word;
            m_length = length;
        }
};

void gameLoop()
{
    word1.set(); //flags error as it cant acces the word1 object
    //I want to be able to access word1 from here
    //Not a copy because that wouldnt change the actual word1
    //I dont want to define it in here because then it would be created again
    //for each loop of gameLoop
}

int main()
{
    Word word1;
    int play = 1;
    while (play ==1){
        gameLoop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a largely simplified version but for the purpose of the game I want the class to be stored externally but for a number of gameplay functions inside gameLoop to be able to access and change the class object.

Comment: Pass `word1` to `gameLoop` as an argument.

Comment: pass it as a parameter `gameLoop(Word word)`

Comment: Probably better as a reference (`gameLoop(Word& word)`)

Comment: btw your wording sounds a bit confused. You want to access an object not a class and classes arent defined in functions (well now it can be done, but usually you dont do it)

Comment: Alternatively you could declare `Word word1;` outside `main` (in global scope) - but that is generally a bad practice

Comment: Once you get that working note that `word1.set();` is still invalid.  You have to pass things to it as that is how you defined it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the dependencies of a function should be stater in the parameter list. If your `gameLoop` function requires a `Word` object, pass it in as an argument. That way, it's clear what objects the function requires to work. This would look something like:

```
void gameLoop(Word& word)
{
    word.set();
    // ^ Obviously you need to supply args here. 
}

int main()
{
    Word word1;
    int play = 1;
    while (play ==1){
        gameLoop(word1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And since you're mutating the Word object in the function, you need to pass it by reference, or else you're just modifying a copy.

Your only other sane option would be to make the word object global, but that should be avoided at all costs. It makes testing more difficult since you need to take into consideration every change that *may* have happened, which makes it difficult to isolate problems.

Comment: So in this case is word (in gameLoop) the same object as word1 (from main)? Not an independent copy?

Comment: @UoMDan If you pass by reference (`&`), yes. Without the `&`, a copy would be made.

Comment: Ahh I think this is what I've been looking for! I think I kept making copies which then disappear over each loop, but this sounds like what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: @UoMDan Yes, if you don't pass by reference, a copy is made, you modify the copy, and then it's destroyed when the function exits. Another other option would be to return the modified word copy. *If* it's the only thing being modified in `gameLoop`, that would be a feasible option as well. Since I've been programming functional lately, I'd say explicitly returning it is better than modifying the argument, but that may be "anti-c++ style". It's been a few years since I've written c++, so idiomatic c++ isn't fresh in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you're structuring you're program this way, you would have to pass it as a parameter to `gameloop`

However, This is a very poor design, since anything you create in `main` and want to access in `gameloop` would have to be passed in as an argument. I would consider a different approach.

You could move the entire loop and variable declarations into `gameLoop` as so:

```
void gameLoop()
{
    Word word1;
    int play = 1;
    while (play ==1){
        word1.set(/*args*/);
    }
}

int main()
{
    gameLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

This way you  won't have to pass a million things into gameloop. Generally in games there's some initialization and finalization that needs to take place as well, and this can all be done in `main` before/after the call to `gameLoop`.

So to answer you original question, you would have to pass `word1` as an argument to `gameLoop()`. So redefine your function to accept a `Word` argument, and then pass in word1. but again, **I would reconsider your current design before its too late**

Comment: I think I will have to pass it, as gameLoop will also have its own functions in turn which may want to change stuff about word1

Comment: I don't know if I'd emphasize needing a design change this much. Unless this is a giant project being marked, fantastic screwups are a great way to learn. It's hard to appreciate proper design until you write some really bad code.

Comment: @UoMDan I don't see how that has anything to do with this, since you could still 100% do that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I guess you're right. I'm just imagining going forward a list of 100 parameters that need to be passed in.